# How to redirect an output to wc by pipeline?

Tags: bash, unix, wc

```
count=`cat "Main Dir/$param/sent.txt"|sort -k2|tail -n-$LAST_SENT_EMAILS_TO_CONSIDER|cut -f1 -d" " -d"  "|cut -f2 -d"@"|cut -f1 -d"."|wc -w $domain`
```

Until the wc, I take "LAST_SENT_EMAILS_TO_CONSIDER" strokes from sent.txt sorted by some parameter that I took.

Now, I want to count how much the content of domain ($domain) repeat in the cut strokes.

I did see similar questions and answers, which say that by reorganizing that command line in other way, it could work.
Can somebody help me with this concrete example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the input, I can't test my solution. But if I understand you correctly, you just want to do

```
... | grep -F "$domain" | wc -l
```

i.e. count how many times $domain appears in the output. `-F` is used to prevent interpreting of special characters (e.g. `.` normally matches anything, but if your domain is `example.com`, you don't want to match `exampleXcom`).

BTW, `grep` can count the line itself, so you can shorten it to

```
... | grep -Fc "$domain"
```

Answer (score 0):

Apology, my mistake, `wc` doesn't count <"expressions">, but only words, strokes or chars.

Yes, as choroba said, that's what I wanted to do, and I can use for it only:

```
...|grep -c "$domain"
```